# .NET Core 3.1, Show dynamic added cshtml

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, razor

I have a .NET Core Razor pages web app, the thing is that I’m trying to make this app to route cshtml files that I add dynamically in the “Pages” folder, the thing is that no matter what if I type the name of this file in the address bar, for example: I added a new cshtml file named test.cshtml. I want to display the page when I enter testsite.com/test.

The only way that this dynamically added cshtml to show up is if I stop the application and rebuild it again. If I do not do this, I get “This localhost page can’t be found”, could it be routing problems? Any suggestion.

**UPDATE: SOLVED**

My application did not have the following nuget

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation

And in ConfigurationServices method, in the Starup

services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false).AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

So I once started adding pages into the "Pages" folder it was able to recognize them

[Startup .cs ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhM36.png)

Comment: _"the thing is that I’m trying to make this app to route cshtml files that I add dynamically in the “Pages” folder"_ - that's not how ASP.NET Core works.

Comment: agree with DAI and your requirement is impossible to realize

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)